# Is there an AT command to force registration/ attach to a 5G NR cell?

Tags: at-command, lte, 5g

I used to "force network attach" to LTE on my Android device using

```
at+cops=0,,,7
```

**Is there an AT command for 5G NR?**

Answer (score 5):

According to *ETSI Technical Specification 127 007*, the AT command which is supposed to force the attach of a specific network is **`AT+WS46`** (*Select Wireless Network*).

---

### Syntax

```
+WS46=[<n>]
```

where **n** defines the stack to be used by the device.

---

### Values of *n*

The values concerning 5G network, though introduced some years ago, have been undefined for a long time. They have finally been specified with *ETSI TS 127 007 V15.5.0* (April 2019). Here is the link of the [latest specification version](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/15.07.00_60/ts_127007v150700p.pdf), to date.

Here it is the full list of supported **n** values:

> **12**  GSM Digital Cellular Systems (GERAN only)
>
> **22**  UTRAN  only
>
> **25**  3GPP Systems (GERAN, UTRAN and E-UTRAN)
>
> **28**  E-UTRAN  only
>
> **29**  GERAN and UTRAN
>
> **30**  GERAN and E-UTRAN
>
> **31**  UTRAN and E-UTRAN
>
> **35**  GERAN, UTRAN, E-UTRAN and NG-RAN
>
> **36**  NG-RAN  only
>
> **37**  NG-RAN and E-UTRAN
>
> **38**  NG-RAN, E-UTRAN and UTRAN
>
> **39**  NG-RAN, E-UTRAN and GERAN
>
> **40**  NG-RAN and UTRAN
>
> **41**  NG-RAN, UTRAN and GERAN
>
> **42**  NG-RAN and GERAN

**NG-RAN** identifies 5G network

---

### TL;DR

In order to force 5G only network you have to provide

```
AT+WS46=36
```

Make sure your device supports it by issuing test command `AT+WS46=?`.

Answer (score 1):

```
10 E-UTRA connected to a 5GCN (see NOTE 5)
11 NR connected to a 5GCN (see NOTE 5)
12 NG-RAN
13 E-UTRA-NR dual connectivity (see NOTE 6)
```

To add to above answer, 5G NR basically has 2 modes one is SA and another NSA (NR + LTE), depending upon your network you can use following commands for 5G force attach

```
SA => standalone
AT+COPS=0,,12

NSA => Non Standalone
AT+COPS=0,,13
```